# ASP.NET vNext on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. Unable to load Kestrel

Tags: mono, ubuntu-14.04, asp.net-core

I've installed mono 3.8.0, installed kvm and ran the  kp=vm upgrade and

My K runtime version is as follows

Active Version              Runtime Location             Alias

---

- 1.0.0-beta3          mono    ~/.k/runtimes        default

After running the kpm restore from the folder containing the project.json file
I get an error while running the k kestrel command.

I guess the following error has to do with the libuv installation, which I also have installed - version 1.4.2, or at least I think so. Has anyone come across this error ?

`System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, kestrel. at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.Exception innerException) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0`

Comment: did you try this: http://olivierlefebvre.tumblr.com/post/101523386694/asp-vnext-alpa4-on-ubuntu ? change alpah4 with the kestrel version you use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was pretty simple. Although I had the kestrel command defined in the project.json file, I did not include the "Kestrel" dependency in the dependencies section.

Once I added that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For beta3, you need mono 3.12..